# Protractor does not automatically start PhantomJS

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, protractor

I'm using `protractor` (with `grunt-protractor-runner` to run my E2E Angular tests), but I can't get PhantomJS to start automatically.

My protractor config looks like this:

```
exports.config = {
    //seleniumAddress: "http://localhost:9515",
    specs: [
        'static_src/test/spec/*.js'
    ],


    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'phantomjs',
        'phantomjs.binary.path':'./node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs',
        'phantomjs.cli.args':['--logfile=phantom.log', '--loglevel=DEBUG']
    }
}
```

My understanding is that with that configuration `protractor` will automatically spin up a PhantomJS instance (found on `phantomjs.binary.path`), run the tests against it, communicating directly using the WebDriver protocol (so no need for a Selenium server), and then spin down the PhantomJS instance.

Given that,

1. Is what I've described above the expected behaviour?
2. Is there anything I need to add to the configuration to make that happen?

Comment: protractor's main goal test with real browsers with webdriver. So I don't think using with phantomjs is a good approach. Phantomjs is perfect for unit testing but protractor with selenium is good for end to end testing in real browsers. There is a demo setup: https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

Comment: PhantomJS is a real browser. It's just a little old (comparably to Chrome 13) and you don't see anything except logs or screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Protractor always needs a Selenium standalone server. You can start it using the webdriver-manager and referring to the address in your `protract.conf.js` *or* you can specify the location of the `jar` and Protractor will start it for you.

Refer the `jar` in your configuration, e.g.:

```
seleniumServerJar: 
  'node_modules/selenium-server/lib/runner/selenium-server-standalone-2.38.0.jar'
```

Using this method, you don't have to worry about the selenium server starting up, but it is a little slower. So if you need to rerun your tests often it is faster to start the it as standalone, independent from Protractor.

Comment: You get full information on this http://protractorsupport.blogspot.in/2015/05/protractor-on-phantomjs-install.html?m=1

Comment: When not using a headless browser (such as `PhantomJS`), one can use `directConnect` (https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js#L67-L70, general architecture: http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/infrastructure) to bypass Selenium and connect directly to the `ChromeDriver` or `FirefoxDriver`. IE is, of course, not supported – there one has to specify `directConnect: false` and a new instance of Selenium standalone is spun off when the tests start.